# Store git repo in database for server use

Tags: git, key-value, rocksdb, git-server

As git repositories are saved on disk in some files, serving a public repo in a high-trafic server may cost too much. And also, git-core just supports cgi that slows serving down too.

I want to know, if i save git repository in a database, such as rocksdb, can improve performance?

For example store git objects in a key-value db with hash as key and a special transformation of object as value, and then use replication, sharding,.... to load balance the DB.

I specially focuse on long latency of disk operation on multiple small files.

This system is just for using in a server not for commiting, staging, ammending, and tracking workspace files for a developer

Comment: Git **is** a database, effectively. Trying to store that in anything other than it's intended storage medium is unlikely to improve performance. Why do you think that serving from a DB would magically "cost less" than serving from disk? Where do you think that DB will end up being stored?

Comment: So if i understood correct, just focusing on improving protocol, like using fastcgi or scgi, in Async fashion, is enough....

Comment: I don't know, because you've not described the problem that you're trying to fix, you've only described your attempted solution. What is the concrete issue that you hit that you want to fix?

Comment: You can use git protocol instead of http protocol to download the repository, which might be faster since it is designed for downloading git.